# Generate clickable link to a file (Python)

Tags: python

I would like to either open a file when my program is run, or alternatively, print a clickable link to the file. After reading some similar-looking questions on SO, I tried as follows:

```
f = open('C:/Users/User/Documents/example.xlsx')
    print(f.name)
```

however, this just prints the file directory as text, so I can't just click on it to open the file.

Is it possible to do what I am asking?

Comment: You want Excel to open the file?

Comment: @James yeah that's right

Comment: I think this library help you - https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/